# How can I get jwt payload from request object in my view

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm using django-rest-framework-jwt in my project. I would like to get user_id from the request object in a view.

I've tried `request.user` but it returns AnonymousUser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.

Comment: Hi! give us a bit more information, like the view code and the responses, it would be very helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.user.user_id
```

You're just missing the .user_id part of your model user id. You almost had it. Congrats :)